# Pass along html element information in ng-click (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to allow users to click an "open in new tab" link, which will essentially push that HTML element into a new window for them. I am not sure how to go about this.

Right now, I can open a new generic window called `newTab.html`.

```
<div ng-repeat="api in apiList[0].accounts">
   <div class="panel panel-info" id="panel1">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseAccountsV{{$index}}" class="collapsed">
            {{api.uri}}
            </a>
            <i class="newTab" ng-click="apiTab()">(Open in new tab)</i>
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseAccountsV{{$index}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
         <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table">
               <tr ng-repeat="method in api.methods">
                  <td>{{method.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{method.desc}}</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Using the ng-click I called `apiTab()`.

```
 $scope.apiTab = function() {
        sessionStorage["apiData"] = "hello";
        window.open("newTab.html")
  };
```

and `newTab.html` is just the following right now.

```
<script>
   var myVars = sessionStorage["apiData"];
   alert(myVars);
</script>
```

Is there an easy way to pass along, or push the `<div id="collapseAccountsV{{$index}}"` to my generic window and for it to keep its formatting (within the `table` layout)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can communicate between windows.

[Window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) will let you send the message to the other window. On the second window you'll need to add an event listener to receive the message(example in previous link.).

You'll want to pass not only the mark-up but also the object that angular is rendering so you can re-render it on the new page. You'll need to include angular in the new page also if you want to ask it to re-render. I'm assuming you'll want user to have access to some functionality so having angular there will make that easier.

In the ng-click you can pass in parameters.

```
 <i ng-click='apiTab(api)'>...</i>
```

I'd suggest you then retrieve the div(or template, or directive) in the apiTab function to be passed in.

Comment: Neat idea! I actually was able to do the `apiTab(api)` you suggested, but then pushed that into a `sessionStorage`, then in my `apiTabController` I just parse the JSON and then re-set it to the local $scope as a functional object again, meaning that I can use my `{{variables}}` and `ng-directives` on the new page.

Comment: Sound like a good implementation. Probably saves you some server overhead on page load also.